# Record Video that can be play in almost all android device powerd by API 8+

Tags: android, video, android-mediaplayer, android-video-player, android-videoview

I have application for sharing videos. I found an issues in HTC Wild fire device, Video is not showing the content which taken by Nexus 7, But i can hear the voice in that video.
I guess it happen because streams encoded with unsupported codecs or unsupported video size. My question Which encoding format supported by all the android devices powered by android API 8+

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the list of supported media formats as captured by Google at http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Any device vendor can choose to **not** support a specific encoding format. If you can connect to your device, please pull `/etc/media_codecs.xml` which provides the list of encoders and decoders supported by the device.

`H.264`, `H.263` & `MPEG4` are pretty well known formats and almost all android devices support the playback of the same, whereas `VP8` is relatively newer format and hence, from your reported problem, I suspect that your device may not be supporting the playback of the same.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I can't able to pull the /etc/media_codecs.xml I guess we need rooted device for that. Also i am using H.264 so I hope it will supported in the HTC Wild fire, So I am suspect the preview resolutions of the video.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Supported Media Formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) this formats support built into the Android platform (and supported in almost all devices even on Android 2.2 or older):

Video:
1. H.264 AVC (Baseline profile) inside MPEG-4 (mp4) or 3GPP container

2. H.263 inside MPEG-4 or 3GPP container
3. MPEG-4 SP inside 3GPP container (3gp)

Audio: AAC LC,AAC HE, mp3.

But you have to be patient with bitrates and video resolution. Some devices cannot handle resolution more than 720p (like H.264 with CABAC on Tegra 2). Most of devices support FPS up to 30. Some devices (old Sony Xperia) has issues with decoding surround sound audio in some formats which will cause silence.